# ProGuard fails when updating to Android SDK 23

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-proguard

I am trying to update the [Umweltzone Android application](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone) to SDK 23. Therefore, I change the project configuration as follows:

```groovy
// Excerpt from Umweltzone/build.gradle
compileSdkVersion 23
// ...
compile "com.android.support:design:23.1.1"
```

When I build a **release** version this **fails** with this error (tailing part):

> ...
>   Note: there were 3 references to unknown classes.
>         You should check your configuration for typos.
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual  /troubleshooting.html#unknownclass)
>
> Note: there were 2 classes trying to access enclosing classes using
>   reflection.
>         You should consider keeping the inner classes attributes
>         (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses').
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
>
> Note: there were 100 unkept descriptor classes in kept class members. 
>         You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes
>         (using '-keep').
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#descriptorclass)
>
> Note: there were 5 unresolved dynamic references to classes or
>   interfaces.
>         You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
>
> Note: there were 3 accesses to class members by means of
>   introspection.
>         You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
>         (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
>         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
>
> Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
>            You probably need to update the library versions.
>            (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
>
> Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please
>   correct the above warnings first.
>   :Umweltzone:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task   ':Umweltzone:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>     > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

The release build does work with SDK 22. The ProGuard configuration can be found [here](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/Umweltzone/blob/master/Umweltzone/proguard.cfg). The full build output can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/6yaACR6Z) since StackOverflow does not let me paste here because of length restrictions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick to the error message, i.e. *correct the above warnings first*.

The *above warning* is:

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil: can't find referenced method
'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,
java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
```

Most likely, you don't need that method. So you can get rid of the warning by adding the below line to the proguard config:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Comment: Nice! This actually fixed the build. Can you explain why this warning occurs even though I just increase the SDK version but did not change the code?

Comment: It looks like a glitch in the latest version of the Google Play Services (or support library).